# Docker Consul service ip advertised as internal docker ip

Tags: docker, consul

I am running a Consul in a docker, the official Consul image, and I have a service registering with the consul. The service registers, but the IP that consul reports when polling its DNS service is the internal docker IP that was used to contact the Consul agent.

```
dig @localhost -p 8600 address-norm.service.consul 

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;address-norm.service.consul.   IN      A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
address-norm.service.consul. 0  IN      A       172.17.0.3
```

Instead of the `172.17.0.3` I want consul to change the service IP to Consuls host IP, because the service hides on this host, only exposing it's needed port. I am not using `Registrator`, the service that I am exposing has `Spring Cloud Consul` api integrated into it.

Edit:

Here is the command I use to start consul in a Docker, my current solution is a python script that uses the HTTP API and extracts the IP address and Port.

```
 docker run -d --name consul --net=host consul agent -server -bootstrap \
   -node docker -ui -client=0.0.0.0 -bind=$NET_IP -advertise=$NET_IP
```

Net_IP is just the local network IP for the host running docker

Comment: Can you show how the docker container is started i.e. with what runtime/config options?

Comment: Updated with docker command

Comment: So is spring cloud consul registering the service in consul? If so see https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/Finchley.SR2/single/spring-cloud.html#ignore-network-interfaces